# ClassNotFoundException: when I try to get a class with Reflect

Tags: java, javac

This is my files:

```
$ tree
.
├── Main.java
└── life
    └── Person.java
```

Main.java

```java
import life.Person;

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Person p = new Person();
    p.sayHi();
  } 
}
```

And I try to compile this code:

```sh
$ javac Main.java -d .
$ java Main
hello world
```

Yeah, this was fine. But when I try to use reflect, so I change my Main.java to this:

```java
import life.Person;

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Class person = Class.forName("life.Person");
  } 
}
```

And compiler throw an error:

```
$ javac Main.java -d .
Main.java:6: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Class person = Class.forName("life.Person");
```

I am very confused, why this code success first and failed in the next?

Why class not found?

Comment: Change `public static void main(String[] args) {`to `public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {`

Comment: And please use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse for programming it makes your life a lot easier (believe me!). They indicate such errors directly as the always compile the code you're currently working on, and thus will indicate and even help you resolve that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception, it means the statement might throw `ClassNotFoundException` at run time and you need determine how to handle it at compile stage.

You can throws it to the caller in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
```

or use a try catch block:

```
try {
    Class person = Class.forName("life.Person");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
     // handle it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't saying your class isn't found; it means "I might throw a checked exception and you need to catch it".

```
import life.Person;

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    try {
        Class person = Class.forName("life.Person");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I have a comment that spells out why it's necessary.  Good enough for me.

Comment: It would be nice to add it to your answer.

Comment: You could add it if you wish.